# No enclosing instance of TYPE is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation

Tags: android, constructor, live-wallpaper

I keep getting this error about No enclosing instance of my WallpaperService is available. So my program will not compile. What exactly does this error mean...?

Where should I go from here. Below is my constructor for myEngine class. The error happens at my **`super();`** method call.

```
public final class myEngine extends Engine implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    LWPService a;
    private i b;
    private SharedPreferences c;
    private LWPService r4_LWPService;

    myEngine(LWPService lwpService) {
        super();
        this.a = r4_LWPService;
        this.b = new i(getSurfaceHolder(),
                r4_LWPService.getApplicationContext());
        this.c = r4_LWPService.getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        this.c.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(this.c, null);
    }
... OTHER CODE...

}
```

Here is the LWPService class

```
public class LWPService extends WallpaperService {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new m(this);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myEngine` class should not be `static` - make it as inner class for `LWPService`.